# Find the power series for $d/dx(\arcsin x)$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

How would you find the general power series for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ , without using the general rule for arcsinx?

I understand it is necessary to use binomial series, but I am having trouble finding the general term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Use Generalized Binomial Theorem  $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\left(1-x^2\right)^{-\dfrac12}$$

Comment: How would you find the general term?

Comment: $$\frac{\left(-\dfrac12\right)\left(-\dfrac12-1\right)\cdots \left[-\dfrac12-(r-1)\right]}{r!}\left(-x^2\right)^r$$  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem  and http://planetmath.org/generalizedbinomialcoefficients